# WordPress: get_permalink doesn't work in plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to build a sitemap plugin ,but am stuck at a simple WordPress loop. Every time I try to get the URL, the site crash. Its the `get_permalink` that is making the loop and crashing the site. I have tested these and non of them works for me:

- `get_permalink`
- `the_permalink`
- `get_post_permalink`
- `get_the_permalink`

The loop:

```
function fa_sitemap_build() {

  // Create/open the file
  $file = fopen( get_template_directory() . '/sitemap.xml','wb');

  $the_query = get_posts('post_type = page');
  foreach ( $the_query as $post ) {

        $title = get_the_title($post->ID);
        $link = get_permalink($post->ID);
        $date = $post->post_modified;

        $url .= '
            <url>
                <title>'.$title.'</title>
                <url>'.$link.'</url>
                <lastmod>'.$date.'</lastmod>
            </url>
        ';

  }
  wp_reset_postdata();


  $sitemap = '
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    '.$url.'
  </urlset>';

  // write content to the file
  fwrite( $file, $sitemap );
  fclose( $file ); // Close the file

}
```

Comment: instead of using $post use another one, it may be conflicting with the global $post variable.

Comment: I tested to change "$the_query as $post" to "$the_query as $item" is do not work. Also tested "setup_postdata( $post )" to "setup_postdata( $item )". Still not work.. any more ide?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments passed to the `get_posts()` must be an array. Try the following code.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        echo $post->title;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $post->post_content;
        echo '<br />';
        echo get_permalink( $post->ID );
    }
```

or you can use the following code as well, it works same.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
    echo '<br />';
    the_content();
    echo '<br />';
    the_permalink();
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Reference:**

- [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) function on Codex

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I am trying to run the loop in a plugin

Comment: Can you enable the WP_DEBUG and screenshot the error? It is working fine in my test bench. Are you sure your plugin is activated. Try deactivating the plugin and reactivting.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property 'use_trailing_slashes' of non-object in