# get_permalink() don't work as form action attribute

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Trying to make sign up form using Wordpress.
The register -page is "page-register". So the link is supposed to point to itself.
This worked earlier without WP and with MAMP but can't get this work with wordpress and LocalWP.

```
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink('register'); ?>" method="post">
```

This go to 404 page. The permalink works as hyperlink but not as the form action attribute.

I also tried site_url() and get_page_link().

Comment: "So the link is supposed to point to itself" this can be done with `#` in the action field

Comment: Alternatively, shouldn't it be `action="<?php echo get_permalink('page-register');?>"` ??

Comment: I meant to say "page-register.php". But no, # dont work either.

Comment: According to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556007/3536236) get permalink expects an ID value rather than a text string. Check your PHP error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was not in the form action, but in the form input name. So I changed this:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

to this:

```
<input type="text" name="uname">
```